# Unsure how to query hidden api in dev tools>network>xhr

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to extract data from this website: https://www.webuycars.co.za/buy-a-car.
I have looked at the dev tools>network>xhr for the responses but I am trying to receive more data than from just the first page of results of vehicles. This is the code for it so far:

```
import json
import scrapy

class carSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'car'
    body = {"to":24,"size":24,"type":"All","filter_type":"all","subcategory":None,"q":"audi","Make":None,"Roadworthy":None,"Auctions":[],"Model":None,"Variant":None,"DealerKey":None,"FuelType":None,"BodyType":None,"Gearbox":None,"AxleConfiguration":None,"Colour":None,"FinanceGrade":None,"Priced_Amount_Gte":0,"Priced_Amount_Lte":0,"MonthlyInstallment_Amount_Gte":0,"MonthlyInstallment_Amount_Lte":0,"auctionDate":None,"auctionEndDate":None,"auctionDurationInSeconds":None,"Kilometers_Gte":0,"Kilometers_Lte":0,"Priced_Amount_Sort":"","Bid_Amount_Sort":"","Kilometers_Sort":"","Year_Sort":"","Auction_Date_Sort":"","Auction_Lot_Sort":"","Year":[],"Price_Update_Date_Sort":"","Online_Auction_Date_Sort":"","Online_Auction_In_Progress":""}
    

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search',
            callback=self.parse,
            body=json.dumps(self.body),
            method="POST")
            


    def parse(self, response):
        response = json.loads(response.body)

        for resp in response['data']:
            yield {
                'Title': resp['OnlineDescription']
            }
```

This is the data I receive:

```
2022-05-04 22:21:42 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2020 Nissan Almera 1.5 Acenta Auto'}
2022-05-04 22:21:42 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Citroen C3 Aircross 1.2T Puretech Sine Auto'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Toyota Hilux 2.4 Gd-6 RB Raider Pick Up Double Cab'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2013 Hyundai i10 1.25 Gls/fluid Auto'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 SYM Symphony JET 14 200'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 Nissan Micra 1.2 Active Visia'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2021 Suzuki Super Carry 1.2i Pick Up Single Cab'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Suzuki AN UB 125 (burgman)'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Honda XRL XR 125l'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Toyota Hilux 2.4 Gd-6 RB Raider Pick Up Double Cab'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Land Rover Defender 110 D300 SE X-Dynamic (221 KW)'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Big Boy TSR 250'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 Renault Kwid 1.0 Dynamique 5-Door'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2013 Tata Indigo 1.4 Manza Ignis'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2018 Datsun GO 1.2 LUX'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2021 Renault Kiger 1.0 Energy ZEN'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2020 Crosby Adventure Bike 400cc'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2012 Jeep Compass 2.0 LTD'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2021 Crosby Adventure Bike 400cc'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Renault Kwid 1.0 Climber 5-Door'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 Suzuki Swift 1.2 GLX'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2022 Volkswagen Polo Classic GP 1.4 Comfortline'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2020 Renault Kwid 1.0 Climber 5-Door Auto'}
2022-05-04 22:21:43 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search>
{'Title': '2019 Yamaha YZ 450 FX'}
```

However I have been trying to query audi as seen in line 7 of the code in the body variable("q":"audi").
No matter what I try, I keep receiving the same data back which is all from the first page. I assume there is something wrong with how I parse my body in scrapy.Request but I am unsure. I have tried different formats of the body like making it a string, directly copy and pasting the payload from the response and also not parsing it as json formatted but rather a string. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,you want to get data from more than one page meaning want to make pagination, If so, then you can follow the next working solution.

```
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class CarsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'car'
    body = {"to":24,"size":24,"type":"All","filter_type":"all","subcategory":None,"q":"","Make":None,"Roadworthy":None,"Auctions":[],"Model":None,"Variant":None,"DealerKey":None,"FuelType":None,"BodyType":None,"Gearbox":None,"AxleConfiguration":None,"Colour":None,"FinanceGrade":None,"Priced_Amount_Gte":0,"Priced_Amount_Lte":0,"MonthlyInstallment_Amount_Gte":0,"MonthlyInstallment_Amount_Lte":0,"auctionDate":None,"auctionEndDate":None,"auctionDurationInSeconds":None,"Kilometers_Gte":0,"Kilometers_Lte":0,"Priced_Amount_Sort":"","Bid_Amount_Sort":"","Kilometers_Sort":"","Year_Sort":"","Auction_Date_Sort":"","Auction_Lot_Sort":"","Year":[],"Price_Update_Date_Sort":"","Online_Auction_Date_Sort":"","Online_Auction_In_Progress":""}

    def start_requests(self):
       
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://website-elastic-api.webuycars.co.za/api/search',
            callback=self.parse,
            body=json.dumps(self.body),
            method="POST",
            headers= {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "User-Agent":"mozilla/5.0"
                }
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        response = json.loads(response.body)
        for item in range(0,6528,24):
            response['total']['value']=item
       
            for resp in response['data']:
                yield {
                    'Title': resp['OnlineDescription']
                }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl()
    process.start()
```

**Output:**

```
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,

 'item_scraped_count': 6528,
```

[screenshot_pagination_source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM5Eo.png)